# What happens to my turns when I ascend?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

If I use all of my turns before I ascend, do I get any more turns when I start over? Or is it like normal play, and I only have my normal number of daily turns that I had before I ascended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They vanish and you start with the normal 40 adventures.